# The value you set has already been locked. To change the value, use the --lock-env option

Tags: magento2, javascript, bin-magento

I'm trying to do

```
php -f bin/magento config:set dev/js/enable_js_bundling 1
```

But I get:

> The value you set has already been locked. To change the value, use the --lock-env option.

What does this mean and how can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have locked the admin / configuration changes using the `app:config:set` command. Now the only option you have is to make necessary changes in your `config.php`.

Entries would be like:

```
 'js' => [
                'merge_files' => '0',
                'minify_files' => '0',
                'minify_exclude' => '
                /tiny_mce/',
                'session_storage_logging' => '0',
                'translate_strategy' => 'dictionary',
                'enable_js_bundling' => '0',
            ],
            'css' => [
                'minify_files' => '0',
                'minify_exclude' => '
                /tiny_mce/
            ',
                'merge_css_files' => '0',
            ],
```

Set values to `1` where you want to enable minification / merging and save this file. After saving run the `php bin/magento app:config:dump` command.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. Now I'm running into this problem: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265174/php-bin-magento-appconfigdump-gives-me-magento-framework-exception-validatore

Answer (score 1):

Can also do

```bash
php -f bin/magento --lock-env config:set dev/js/enable_js_bundling 1
```

Which will override the locked setting with new one and lock it again

Comment: Is there any way to remove entry from env.php file? For eg. i want to remove merge and minify config from env.php. It was added using --lock-env command. but now i want to remove as it override the configuration