# php bin/magento app:config:dump gives me [Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException] Path "app/etc" cannot be used with "app/etc"

Tags: magento2, configuration, bin-magento

I'm trying to change some settings, and [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/264936/77469) has already been very helpful.
But now `php bin/magento app:config:dump` gives me

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException]
>    Path "/var/www/magento-site/application/releases/3/app/etc/" cannot be used with directory "/var/www/magento-site/application/releases/3/app/etc/"

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're not using proper file permissions.

Make sure your files are read- and writable for the correct user and group.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/trouble/readiness/tshoot_rc_perms.html

> Directories in the Magento file system must be writable by the web server user and the Magento file system owner, if applicable.

Magento provides this command to set proper permission:

```
cd /var/www/html/magento2 && find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+w {} + && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

> The users require write access in developer mode but not in production mode.

So you may want to execute also this line if you're running development mode:

```
cd /var/www/html/magento2 && find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} + && find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} +
```